# Android NumberPicker hiding increment and decrement buttons

Tags: java, android

I am using a [NumberPicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html) and am targeting API 11 and above (3.0 and up), so I am using the supported [NumberPicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html). This is being used in a timer application. I want to be able to hide the increment and decrement buttons at will so that the buttons will not take up space in the layout when hidden. I have attempted to do this:

```
View increment = secs.getChildAt(0);
increment.setVisibility(View.GONE);
View decrement = secs.getChildAt(2);
decrement.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

where secs is my NumberPicker for seconds in the timer. If I try to hide the place where it displays the number (an EditText widget) it hides just fine, but the above code does nothing.

So, my question is, how do I accomplish hiding the increment and decrement buttons? I would really like to avoid making my own custom number picker like I have read about in some other posts, but if that is truly the only way I'm willing to try it.

Thanks!

Here is additional code as requested.
Code in onClick method for when stopwatch is started:

```
if (stopPush)
{
startTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - elapsedTime;
}
else
{
startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
mHandler.removeCallbacks(startTimer);
mHandler.postDelayed(startTimer, 0);
```

Code that handles stopwatch abilities:

```
private Runnable startTimer = new Runnable()
{
public void run()
{
    elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    updateTimer(elapsedTime);
    mHandler.postDelayed(this, REFRESH_RATE);
}
};
```

Code for calculating and updating stopwatch time:

```
this.millis = (int) (elapsedTime / 100);
this.seconds = (int) (elapsedTime / 1000);
this.minutes = (seconds / 60);
this.hours = (minutes / 60);
millis = millis % 10;
seconds = seconds % 60;
minutes = minutes % 60;
hours = hours % 24;
runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
{
public void run()
{
    hrs.setValue(hours);
}
});
runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
{
public void run()
{
    mins.setValue(minutes);
}
});
runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
{
public void run()
{
    secs.setValue(seconds);
}
});
runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
{
public void run()
{
    mills.setValue((int) millis);
}
});
```

Answer (score 4):

When you do not provide the min- and max-value on the numberpicker, the buttons are (normally) not shown.

Comment: If I don't provide the min and max values will I run into any other problems? Is there a default min and max built in if not provided that could cause crashes? Thanks for the suggestion! That is definitely simple enough as long as everything else still works properly.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and the buttons do indeed disappear, but there is no effect when I try to call setValue to change the value of the numberpicker. It just stays at 0.

Comment: This is not what I expected. Could you post some code on what you do exactly?

Comment: I suppose mills etc are of type 'NumberPicker'? Are you sure that your threads are properly executed? When you add a breakpoint to those methods, do you enter these methods?

Comment: Yes, it all works perfectly prior to commenting out the setMin and setMax method call portions. And yes, mills, etc are the numberpicker's.

Comment: @barrel This doesn't seem to work for me. I have min/max values set and the buttons to not appear. Could you check my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16345799/numberpicker-within-dialogfragment). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Developer site says,

NumberPicker is a widget that enables the user to select a number from a predefined range. There are two flavors of this widget and which one is presented to the user depends on the current theme.

If the current theme is derived from `Theme` the widget presents the current value as an editable input field with an increment button above and a decrement button below. Long pressing the buttons allows for a quick change of the current value. Tapping on the input field allows to type in a desired value.

If the current theme is derived from `Theme_Holo` or `Theme_Holo_Light` the widget presents the current value as an editable input field with a lesser value above and a greater value below. Tapping on the lesser or greater value selects it by animating the number axis up or down to make the chosen value current. Flinging up or down allows for multiple increments or decrements of the current value. Long pressing on the lesser and greater values also allows for a quick change of the current value. Tapping on the current value allows to type in a desired value.

So you may try Changing the Theme.