# android: number picker can't scroll

Tags: android, numberpicker

I want to implement a number picker:
My xml file:

```
 <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/np"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

And in activity:

```
private NumberPicker mNumberpicker;
private String[] nums;
...
mNumberpicker = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.np);
nums = new String[21];
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        nums[i] = Integer.toString(i * 5);
    }

    // Set the max and min values of the numberpicker, and give it the
    // array of numbers created above to be the displayed numbers
    mNumberpicker.setMaxValue(20);
    mNumberpicker.setMinValue(0);
    mNumberpicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
    mNumberpicker.setDisplayedValues(nums);
```

But, the number picker have (+) button and (-) button. What I want is the number picker that cant scroll. Not the two button (+) and (-).
What's my wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the `NumberPicker` not to show increment/decrement buttons. To achieve that you could avoid setting the max/min value (e.g. no call to `set(Min|Max)Value())`. From this: [Android NumberPicker hiding increment and decrement buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808830/android-numberpicker-hiding-increment-and-decrement-buttons)